# Node project stopped working after I updated Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I had my project in Node.js, it worked perfectly. When I tried to deploy it to Heroku it said that I had to specify my node version in `package.json`, so I added
"engines": {
"node": "15.x"
},
to it, and when I did that, the library `discord-youtube-api` stopped working, when I try to get a youtube video it crashes, I tried deleting the engines part, deleting `node_modules`, package, package-lock and reinstalling again, do `npm init` again, get back to a previous commit and nothing worked. Any idea?

Comment: check out node version manager: https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b

Comment: That was it! I downgraded my node version to 14.15.6 (stable) and rewrote engines and now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Node version manager: https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b?gi=c86812913c96